# calling a function within main = do haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

**hi guys, new to haskell and i was wondering what exactly would solve this error im getting when i try to call the play_game function within main.
ignore the bottom half with the guards, as i was just messing around with them with random values to try to fix things up.

[haskell code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIh0i.png)

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIh0i.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS4IN.png

{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: voting to close

Answer (score 2):

1. your syntax on readLn is wrong - correct would be:
   something <- readLn :: IO Int
2. you main funciton is of type IO GHC.Types.Any in short: IO a but your funciton play_games returns something of type (Num a) => a.
   A do notation's last satement has always to be of the returning type... (remember: do notation is only syntactic shugar for the use of (<*>)

for example:

```
main = do
   a <- fs
   b <- as
   pure (f a)
```

is simmilar to:

```
fs <*> as
```

so in case of your example a woring solution would be:

```
main :: IO Int
main = do
    putStrLn "Please input total number of games."
    numGames <- readLn :: IO Int
    player1 <- readLn :: IO Int
    player2 <- readLn :: IO Int
    print player1
    print player2
    return $ play_games player1 player2 numGames (0,0)

play_games :: (Eq a1, Eq a2, Num a1, Num a2, Num a3) => a1 -> a2 -> p -> (a4, a3) -> a3
play_games player1 player2 numGames score
    | player1 == 0&& player2 == 1 = snd score + 1
```